# Generate new div for each post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am just curious is it possible to auto generate new div for each post using php function .

I have a function which count post numbers , how i could use it , I know that it's should be if function for example if ($CurrentNumbers > 1 ) {
create new div }  , but I am totally beginner , here is function

```html
function Get_Post_Number($postID){
 $postNumberQuery = new WP_Query('orderby=date&posts_per_page=-1');
 $counter = 1;
 $postCount = 0;
 while ($postNumberQuery->have_posts()) : $postNumberQuery->the_post();
  if ($postID == get_the_ID()){
   $postCount = $counter;
   echo("true");
  } else {
   $counter++;
  }
 endwhile;
 return $postCount;
}
```

```html
//Display all posts in one div//
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?>
  <?php echo get_excerpt(); ?>


  <?php endwhile;?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php
  $count_posts = wp_count_posts();

  $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
  ?>


</div>
<?php if ($currentNumber > 1 ) {  

}
```

Comment: If you just want each post in its own `col-sm-4` div, then put the opening and closing tag _inside_ the loop, not outside of it …

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'd do it, you begin a count outside of the loop that increase on every post, once the third is met (which is technically the fourth due to starting at 0) close the div, open a new one and reset the count to -1 to start it again.

Cheers

```
    <?php
    $count =  0;
    if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


            <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
            <?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>

            <?php if($count == 3) {
                echo '</div>';
                echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
                $count = -1;
            }
          $count++;
            ?>


        <?php endwhile;?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```